# Post-Hoc pairwise comparison for slope (interaction term) in R?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, ancova

I have been using scripts from package "Agricolae" but realised today that it compares only between the intercepts.

1. I expect that since i am testing for the interaction term using ANCOVA, the post-hoc test should do that as well instead of being a more general comparison. Or am i wrong?
2. Are there are scripts/methods that does pairwise comparison for "slope" and "intercept"??
3. If Scheffe is not available, what is the next best option for unequal sample sizes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using R to do the analysis, the **emmeans** package has an `emtrends` function that estimates estimated marginal slopes. e.g.,

```
library(emmeans)
emtrends(model, pairwise ~ treatment, var = "dose")
```

The package's vignette on interactions, which is viewable [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html), gives some examples and more discussion.

Comment: I’m trying to plot a histogram of the slopes from emtrends. Is there a way to add_xy_position to the emtrends output so I can use stat_pvalue_manual to put the emtrends p-values on the histogram? I can see add_xy_position works with emmeans, but can’t get it to work with emtrends

Comment: Use as.data.frame() on the results, then add whatever columns you need.

Comment: I currently run into memory issues with this command for a bigger model (100k+ rows). Do you know of a way to subsample the data used in this command?

Comment: I added a feature in version 1.5.0 that is creating this issue because I wasn't careful in how I coded the setup. I suggest reverting back to 1.4.8 or installing the patched version from the GitHub site.